# Serialization on rdd vs dataframe Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, closures

**EX1**. This with an RDD gives Serialization as we expect with or without Object and val num being the culprit, fine:

```
object Example {
 val r = 1 to 1000000 toList
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(r,3)
 val num = 1
 val rdd2 = rdd.map(_ + num)
 rdd2.collect  
}
Example
```

**EX2**. Using a Dataframe in similar fashion, however, does not. Why is that as it looks sort of the same? What am I missing here?

```
object Example {
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val n = 1 
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    ("r1", 1, 1),
    ("r2", 6, 4),
    ("r3", 4, 1),
    ("r4", 1, 2)
    )).toDF("ID", "a", "b")
df.repartition(3).withColumn("plus1", $"b" + n).show(false)
}
Example
```

Reasons not entirely clear to me on DF, would expect similar behaviour. Looks like DSs circumvent some issues, but I may well be missing something.

Running on Databricks gives plenty of Serializatiion issues, so do not think that is affecting things, handy to test.

Comment: change `n` to `lit(n)` in your example, and it should be fine.   

first parameter is a column, therefore second parameter is expected to be a column.  

If you use a scalar value, you should tell spark about it, otherwise, it'll try to find variable (`n`) and expect it to be of `Column` type, which is not true in your case

Comment: n works fine, rthat's the point, but I got it, was just wanting to be very exact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple and more fundamental than distinction between `RDD` and `Dataset`:

- The first piece of code evaluates a function

  ```
  _ + num
  ```

  therefore it has to be computed and evaluated.
- The second piece of code doesn't. Following

  ```
  $"b" + n
  ```

  is just a value, therefore no closure computation and subsequent serialization is required.

If this is still not clear you can think about it this way:

- The former piece of code tells Spark **how to do something**.
- The latter piece of code tells Spark **what to do**. Actual code that is executed is generated in different scope.

If your `Dataset` code was closer to it's `RDD` counterpart, for example:

```
object Example {
  import spark.implicits._

  val num = 1
  spark.range(1000).map(_ + num).collect
}
```

or

```
Example {
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

  val num = 1
  val f = udf((x: Int) => x + num) 
  spark.range(1000).select(f($"id")).collect
}
```

it would fail with serialization exception, same as `RDD` version does.